# Recharts wordwrap x-axis label

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I want to word-wrap long labels like in this [demo](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321).
Supposedly [this PR](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/pull/243) supports it, but I couldn't get it to work with

```
<XAxis dataKey="name" interval={0} width={30} label={<Text width={30} />} />
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lisamartin00/exasjofp/) done by [lisamartin00](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/961#issuecomment-430799345)

She used a custom axis tick:

```
const CustomizedAxisTick = React.createClass({
  render () {
    const {x, y, payload} = this.props;

    return <Text x={x} y={y} width={75} textAnchor="middle" verticalAnchor="start">{payload.value}</Text>
  }
});
```

Comment: any way to implement ellipsis ... for too long texts?

Answer (score 2):

The above answer might do it if your tick is large, but for me it didn't work.

Although the docs mention that the `width` prop on the `<Text/>` component (from recharts) receives a `Number`, you can also pass in width as `px`.

Keep the `fontSize` and `width` prop the same on your custom Tick component to get a break-word feature.

```
const CustomXAxisTick = ({ x, y, payload }: any) => {
    if (payload && payload.value) {
      return (
        <Text
            fontSize={"12px"}
            width={"12px"}
            x={x} 
            y={y} 
            textAnchor="middle" 
            verticalAnchor="start"
        >{payload.value}</Text>
      );
    }
    return null;
};
<XAxis interval={0} tick={<CustomXAxisTick/>} dataKey="name" />
```

**Bonus:** `interval={0}` prevents your ticks from disappearing easily.

Comment: This only seems to work because "12px" is seen as invalid, causing recharts to fall back to putting every word in its own `tspan` element: `<tspan>Foo</tspan><tspan>Bar</tspan>`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a CustomXAxisTick like in J.E.C's answer, but with a dynamically calculated width:

```
import {BarChart, XAxis, Text /*...*/} from "recharts";
import AutoSizer from "react-virtualized-auto-sizer";

const Y_AXIS_WIDTH = 80; // (approximation)

const CustomXAxisTick = ({ x, y, payload, width }) => {
  if (payload?.value) {
    return (
      <Text
        width={width}
        x={x}
        y={y}
        textAnchor="middle"
        verticalAnchor="start"
      >{payload.value}</Text>
    );
  }
  return null;
};

const MyBarChart = ({barData}) => {
  return (
    <AutoSizer>
      {({height, width}) => (
        <BarChart data={barData}>
          <XAxis /*...*/ 
            tick={<CustomXAxisTick width={(width - Y_AXIS_WIDTH) / barData.length} />}
            />
          {/*...*/}
        </BarChart>
      )}
    </AutoSizer>
  );
}
```